# Writing pandas DataFrame to Excel with different formats for different columns

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I am trying to write a pandas `DataFrame` to an `.xlsx` file where different numerical columns would have different formats. For example, some would show only two decimal places, some would show none, some would be formatted as percents with a "%" symbol, etc.

I noticed that `DataFrame.to_html()` has a `formatters` parameter that allows one to do just that, mapping different formats to different columns.  However, there is no similar parameter on the `DataFrame.to_excel()` method. The most we have is a `float_format` that is global to all numbers.

I have read many SO posts that are at least partly related to my question, for example:

- [Use the older `openpyxl` engine to apply formats one cell at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24493918/pandas-set-cell-format-in-excel-writer/24496905#24496905). This is the approach with which I've had the most success. But it means writing loops to apply formats cell-by-cell, remembering offsets, etc.
- [Render percentages by changing the table data itself into strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18115741/writing-percentages-in-excel-using-pandas). Going the route of altering the actual data inspired me to try dealing with decimal place formatting by calling `round()` on each column before writing to Excel - this works too, but I'd like to avoid altering the data.
- Assorted others, mostly about date formats

Are there other more convenient Excel-related functions/properties in the pandas API that can help here, or something similar on `openpyxl`, or perhaps some way to specify output format metadata directly onto each column in the `DataFrame` that would then be interpreted downstream by different outputters?

Comment: what about removing ALL formats? Anyone know if there's a quick way to do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this with Pandas 0.16 and the XlsxWriter engine by accessing the underlying workbook and worksheet objects:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a Pandas dataframe from some data.
df = pd.DataFrame(zip(
    [1010, 2020, 3030, 2020, 1515, 3030, 4545],
    [.1, .2, .33, .25, .5, .75, .45],
    [.1, .2, .33, .25, .5, .75, .45],
))

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

# Get the xlsxwriter objects from the dataframe writer object.
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

# Add some cell formats.
format1 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '#,##0.00'})
format2 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0%'})
format3 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'h:mm:ss AM/PM'})

# Set the column width and format.
worksheet.set_column('B:B', 18, format1)

# Set the format but not the column width.
worksheet.set_column('C:C', None, format2)

worksheet.set_column('D:D', 16, format3)

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

Output:

[image]

See also [Working with Python Pandas and XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/working_with_pandas.html).

Answer (score 3):

As you rightly point out applying formats to individual cells is extremely inefficient.

openpyxl 2.4 includes native support for Pandas Dataframes and named styles.

https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changes.html#id7