# Apply conditional formatting in Excel using pandas does not work

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have spent hours trying all possible pandas style methods for conditional formatting for Excel sheet but none of them worked...
I have a dataframe like this below.

```
         Category      Month   Sales    Margin  Margin_Rate
0              TV       July   50000  10354.64     0.207093
1          Steros     August   45000  39379.38     0.875097
2          Phones  September   22000   8130.23     0.369556
3     Cell Phones    October   90000   8089.23     0.089880
4  Video Consoles   November   12000   8564.69     0.713724
5     Video Games   December    7000   3187.74     0.455391
6       Wearables    January   28000   8470.51     0.302518
7         Tablets   February   75000   8649.36     0.115325
8          Movies      March   25000  20372.73     0.814909
9         Laptops      April  100000  62309.34     0.623093
```

(1). I am trying to do the number formatting using style.format() from pandas but it never worked.
(2). Trying to apply the cell background color based on conditions using style.apply or style.applymap and also it never worked.

Here is my code:

```
# First of all I tried style.format(precision=1)
df.style.format(precision=1)  <--- This causes TypeError: format() got an unexpected keyword argument 'precision'. Any idea why? 

# And then I tried the dictionary approach. No error from this but it does not format numbers
df.style.format({'Margin': '{:.1f}', 'Margin_Rate': '{:.2f}'})

# And then I tried apply background-color and none of them worked..
def highlight_cell(val):
    color = 'yellow' if val == 'Movies' else ''
    return f"bacground-color: {color}"

df.style.applymap(highlight_cell)

# No number formatting nor background color change in the excel sheet...
df.to_excel('retails.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
```

None of them worked...
Any idea please?
Or did I miss anything?

Thank you.

**[ Adding df.to_dict() as Kraigolas recommends ]:**

```
{'Category': {0: 'TV', 1: 'Steros', 2: 'Phones', 3: 'Cell Phones', 4: 'Video Consoles', 5: 'Video Games', 6: 'Wearables', 7: 'Tablets', 8: 'Movies', 9: 'Laptops'}, 'Month': {0: 'July', 1: 'August', 2: 'September', 3: 'October', 4: 'November', 5: 'December', 6: 'January', 7: 'February', 8: 'March', 9: 'April'}, 'Sales': {0: 50000, 1: 45000, 2: 22000, 3: 90000, 4: 12000, 5: 7000, 6: 28000, 7: 75000, 8: 25000, 9: 100000}, 'Margin': {0: 10354.64, 1: 39379.38, 2: 8130.23, 3: 8089.23, 4: 8564.69, 5: 3187.74, 6: 8470.51, 7: 8649.36, 8: 20372.73, 9: 62309.34}, 'Margin_Rate': {0: 0.2070928, 1: 0.8750973333333333, 2: 0.3695559090909091, 3: 0.08988033333333333, 4: 0.7137241666666667, 5: 0.45539142857142856, 6: 0.3025182142857143, 7: 0.1153248, 8: 0.8149092, 9: 0.6230934}}
```

Comment: you should update your pandas version if `precision` is not a recognised keyword argument. It was added in pandas 1.3.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few issues in your code:

- typo in "background"
- your function should return `''` or `None` if no style is applied, not `"background-color:"`
- you should export the return of `df.style.applymap`, not `df`

To set up the decimals, use `float_format="%0.1f"` in `to_excel`:

```
# And then I tried apply background-color and none of them worked..
def highlight_cell(val):
    color = 'yellow' 
    return f"background-color: {color}" if val == 'Movies' else ''

(df.style.applymap(highlight_cell)
   .to_excel('retails.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', float_format="%0.1f")
)
```

output:

[image: excel highlight]

Formatting without excel export:

```
(df.style.applymap(highlight_cell)
   .format({'Margin': '{:.1f}', 'Margin_Rate': '{:.2f}'})
   #.to_excel('retails.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
)
```

output:

[image: pandas formatting]

Comment: Thank you very much! But do you know why the number formatting doesn't work?

Comment: Great! but any idea why style.format() does not work?

Comment: Yes, you would need to pipe the different commands (if you just run `df.style` this does nothing in place), and `df.style.format` does not always work for excel export. NB. If you need different precision for different columns, you need to use `ExcelWriter` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29974672/writing-pandas-dataframe-to-excel-with-different-formats-for-different-columns))

Comment: I see. It is pretty frustrating that the method shown in panda official site does not really work as it instructs....  and yes I noticed df.style is quite different from other methods. df = df.style.format() cannot be printed... By the way, what is the output of your 2nd output (Formatting without excel export)?

Comment: It's from a jupyter notebook

Comment: Thank you for the helps! Yes, most of articles or videos is about the output in Jupyter notebook. Only few about excel output and it is strange that they show it works from their end but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: @JasonT. I think export to excel is probably not the primary concern of pandas development (which I understand)